# How to hide an alert and show another alert after a button is clicked in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm designing a game in Vue JS called Higher or Lower. The code below will trigger an alert to be shown on the webpage every time one of the buttons is clicked. However, the alert does not disappear after a button is clicked again.

I want to make is so that the current alert disappears after a button click so that the next alert shows up. That way, there is only one relevant alert on the webpage.

This is what the webpage looks like:

[image]

```
<template>
<div class="main">
    <h2>
        {{ message }}
    </h2>
    <div class="alert alert-success" v-if="correctMessage">
        {{ correctMessage }}
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" v-if="incorrectMessage">
        {{ incorrectMessage }}
    </div>
    <h3>
        The current number is: <strong> {{ currentNumber }} </strong>
    </h3>
    <h4 class="score"> SCORE: {{ score }} / 8 </h4>
    <p> Is the next number higher or lower? </p>
    <button @click="guessHigher" class="button1">
        Higher
    </button>
    <button @click="guessLower" class="button2">
        Lower
    </button>
    <p> {{ numbers }} </p>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "HighLow",
    data: function () {
        return {
            // the collection of numbers that the user will need to progress thru
            numbers: [],

            // the users current guess
            guess: null,

            // the users score
            score: 0,

            // Some info text to display to the user after their guess
            correctMessage: '',

            incorrectMessage: ''
        }
    },
    computed: {
        currentNumber: function () {
            return this.numbers[this.score];
        },

        nextNumber: function () {
            return this.numbers[this.score + 1];
        }
    },

    methods: {
        // Prepare the numbers array
        // reset the game logic
        initGame: function () {
            this.score = 0;
            this.guess = null;
            this.numbers = this.generateNumbers(10)
        },

        guessHigher: function () {
            // work out if the guess is correct...
            var correct = this.nextNumber > this.currentNumber;
            if (correct)
            {
                this.correctMessage = 'Correct!';
                this.score++;
            }
            else
            {
                this.incorrectMessage = 'Incorrect! Game Over!';
                this.shuffle(this.numbers);
                this.score = 0;
            }

            if (this.score === 8)
            {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Brilliant. Absolutely brilliant. You are not a monkey after all.',
                    text: 'Play again?',
                    imageUrl: 'https://unsplash.it/400/200',
                    imageWidth: 400,
                    imageHeight: 200,
                    imageAlt: 'Custom image',
                })
                this.shuffle(this.numbers);
                this.score = 0;
            }
        },

        guessLower: function () {
            // work out if the guess is correct...
            var correct = this.nextNumber < this.currentNumber;
            if (correct)
            {
                this.correctMessage = 'Correct!';
                this.score++;
            }
            else
            {
                this.incorrectMessage = 'Incorrect! Game Over!';
                this.shuffle(this.numbers);
                this.score = 0;
            }

            if (this.score === 8)
            {
                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Brilliant. Absolutely brilliant. You are not a monkey after all.',
                    text: 'Play again?' ,
                    imageUrl: 'https://unsplash.it/400/200',
                    imageWidth: 400,
                    imageHeight: 200,
                    imageAlt: 'Custom image',
                })
                this.shuffle(this.numbers);
                this.score = 0;
            }
        },

        shuffle: function (array) {
            return array.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
        },

        generateNumbers: function (num) {
            var randomNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
            return this.shuffle(randomNumbers).slice(0, num);
        },

        // MY METHODS

        disableButton: function() {

        },

        getHint: function () {
            for (var i in this.numbers) {
                return i;
            }

            // currentNumber and numbers
        },
    },
    mounted: function () {
        // component is ready for action!
        this.initGame();
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to change the value of `correctMessage` to an empty string at some point

Comment: also please note that an `alert` is typically the short name given to the alert box displayed using javascript function `alert()`. That doesn't change much to your question but it could quicly become confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add this lines inside of your functions `guessHigher` & `guessLower`

```
if (correct) {
  this.incorrectMessage = '' // +
  this.correctMessage = 'Correct!'
  this.score++
} else {
  this.correctMessage = '' // +
  this.incorrectMessage = 'Incorrect! Game Over!'
  this.shuffle(this.numbers)
   this.score = 0
}
```

also should be more convenient to use `v-show` directive in your template:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" v-show="correctMessage">
  {{ correctMessage }}
  </div>
<div class="alert alert-danger" v-show="incorrectMessage">
  {{ incorrectMessage }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My bad. there is no .remove() function in Vuejs. Mixed something up there.

```vuejs
var vue = new Vue({
  el:"YourDivClassOrID",
  data: {
    isShowing:false,
  }
})
```

Then you can change the `isShowing` variable to **true** or **false** to see or hide it.

Hope this would help you :)

Comment: I would rather hide it than completely remove it. Not a big deal here but if OP gets the habit of using `remove()` , when the element he actually wants to hide/show will have events associated to it, using `remove()` will break the thing.

Comment: I don't know any `.Remove()` method in Vue, can you add a link to the doc ?

Comment: doesn't exists in Vue, maybe he thought that should work as the `.Remove()` of vanilla JS.